# Normal Distribution, negative Z, trying to find variance

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a D ~ N(5, 27 + sigma^2) and P(D < 0) = 0.2. I need to find the variance.

I get this far:

[image]

However, I am stuck how to convert to an equivalent formula containing only Z values.

The answer says this but i don't understand how they calculated it:

[image]

Full mark scheme (there is a B1 mark for getting exactly 0.8416):

[image]

Comment: Your tables may say $P(Z\le -0.8416)=0.2$ or equivalently $P(Z\le 0.8416)=0.8$ or $P(Z\gt 0.8416)=0.2$.  In R the code `qnorm(0.2)` gives `-0.8416212`.  Then solve for $\sigma^2 =\left(\frac{-5}{-0.8416}\right)^2-27$ though I am not sure where the $27$ comes from

Comment: @Henry Our tables for the exam go from Z = 0 to 4, giving phi(z) from 0.5 to 1.0. I can't see how they got 0.8416 from our tables.

Comment: What do your tables say for $\Phi(Z)$ when $Z=0.8416$?  Do they give $\Phi(0.84)=0.7995$ and $\Phi(0.85)=0.8023$? Or something in between?

Comment: @Henry Z = 0.84 is 0.7995 and Z = 0.85 is 0.8023

Comment: @Henry Our exams/mark schemes assume we use this table, but I cannot understand how they expect us to get that exact value to 4dp. My calculator has inverse normal but it requires the standard deviation.

Comment: I will post the full mark scheme up for you in the question.

Comment: If you have inverse normal, then apply it to $0.2$ (or $0.8$) and use a mean of $0$ and standard deviation of $1$ corresponding to a standard normal $Z$.  It should give something close to $-0.8416212$ (or $+0.8416212$)

Comment: @Henry Thank you so much. Makes complete sense now.

Comment: @Henry If you add an answer too I can give you even more upvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Requested from comments:*

Your tables may say $P(Z≤−0.8416)=0.2$ or equivalently $P(Z≤0.8416)=0.8$ or $P(Z>0.8416)=0.2$.

Or if your tables give $\Phi(0.84)=0.7995$ and $\Phi(0.85)=0.8023$ then you can interpolate between them to get approximately the same value.

In R the code `qnorm(0.2)` gives `-0.8416212`.  If your calculator does inverse normal, then apply it to $0.2$ and use a mean of $0$ and standard deviation of $1$ corresponding to a standard normal $Z$. It too should give something close to $−0.8416212$.

Then solve for $\sigma^2 =\left(\frac{-5}{-0.8416}\right)^2-27$ though I am not sure where the $27$ comes from

Comment: Sorry, the variance was 27 + sigma squared